# Programmer Beginner - PHP loop repeats same value continously

Tags: foreach

Just started to learn how to program and need some basic help with loops (trying to do exercises as I learn from online materials).

In the code below, I'm trying to print out values in a row of 10, and then produce a new table row after the number of values have exceeded 10. However, I'm in a muddle with my loops and it's just prints out the same value, continuously, without going to the next value.

Comment: Please include more of the code in your question. What you have provided does not show where the "while" or "foreach" loops end.

Comment: The code is incomplete, What do you want to print and where?

Comment: also check your html tags they look strange

Comment: As you're initializing your counters __inside__ the foreach loop, that really isn't surprising.... and I can't see what that while loop is supposed to be doing

Comment: have updated the code now - sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guideline, if you're going to intermix code and markup like this, you might look at alternative syntax.

Your problem is that your output loop is inside the fetching of the rows.  The fetching of the rows is what should trigger the incrementing of your counter.

```
$res = $handle->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Ice Cream</th>
    <tr>
    <tr>  
 <?php
    $c = 0; // Our counter

    foreach($res as $row) {

    // Each Nth iteration would be a new table row

      if($c % 10 == 0 && $c != 0) // If $c is divisible by $n...
      {
        // New table row
        echo '</tr><tr>';
      }
      $c++;
      ?>
        <td>
          //etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are initializing your iterator variables ($c and $n) inside the loop. They should be initialized outside the loop.

You should replace your `while` loop with an `if` statement. Or you could probably do away with it altogether.

Try this:

```
 <?php
   $c = 0; // Our counter
   $n = 10; // Each Nth iteration would be a new table row
 ?> 
 <?php foreach($res as $row): ?>
   <tr>  
   <?php 
   if($c % $n == 0 && $c != 0){ // If $c is divisible by $n... ?>
     //New table row
     echo '</tr><tr>';
   }
   $c++;
   ?>
   <td><form method="POST" action="Ice Cream Choice.php" <?php echo $row['IceCream']; ?>>         
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row['IceCream']; ?>"/>       
   </form>
   </td>
   </tr>
 <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify the HTML as to make the example clearer. This is one way you can write the program.

```
// Fetch the array of rows.
$res = $handle->fetchAll();

// Keep count of which row number we're on. The first
// row we will be on is row 1.
$rowCounter = 1;

// Everything in the block (between the braces) is done
// sequentially for each row in the result set.
foreach ($res as $row)
{
  // Print out the ice cream on a line.
  echo $row, '<br/>';

  // If we have reached a row which is a multiple of 2
  // then print a horizontal rule.
  if ($rowCounter % 2 == 0)
  {
    echo '<hr/>';
  }

  // Increase the row counter because we're about to
  // start the loop again for the next row.
  $rowCounter = $rowCounter + 1;
}
```

Let us assume:

```
$res = array('vanilla', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 
             'raspberry', 'cherry');
```

Now lets evaluate the loop by hand to see what is going on. To do this we're going to maintain a table of our variables and output. Each row is one complete iteration of the loop.

```
$rowCounter | $row         | output
------------+--------------+------------
1           | --           | --
2           | 'vanilla'    | vanilla<br/>
3           | 'chocolate'  | vanilla<br/>chocolate<br/><hr/>
4           | 'strawberry' | vanilla<br/>chocolate<br/><hr/>strawberry<br/>
etc.
```